# How I can map Unity to inject instance of container?

Tags: c#, winforms, unity-container

How I can map Unity to inject instance of container, I'm using DependencyAttribute Class but I alway get a instance null.

I can try:

```
    static void Main()
    {
        using (var container = new UnityContainer())
        {
            container.RegisterType<Invoice, Invoice>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
            container.RegisterType<Form1>().RegisterInstance<IUnityContainer>(container);

            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(container.Resolve<Form1>());
        }
    }

   public partial class Form1 : Form
   {
       [Dependency]
        public IUnityContainer Container { get; set; }
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            var invoice = Container.Resolve<Invoice>();
        }
    }
```

[image: Value cannot be null.Parameter name: container]

Comment: *Where* is `Container` null? If it's in the constructor, that's expected behaviour - properties are resolved after the constructor has run.

Comment: Also, note that you don't need to call `RegisterInstance(container)`. The container already has a registration for itself, and if you try and dispose of the container you will get a StackOverflowException.

Comment: Sorry my `Form1.Container` is null not get the intance of container.

Comment: Yes, but at what point in your code is the Container null? You don't show where you are trying to use it. Please edit your code to show where you are trying to use Container.

Comment: Added code with exception, thank you.

Comment: No, no, and no. You are implementing the  http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/. Do NOT 1) inject the container itself 2) use property injection. You should use constructor injection instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so you can't access the `Container` property from inside the constructor because it has not been set yet.

If you think about how you would manually create the object, it should become obvious why not:

```
Form1 myForm = new Form1();
myForm.Container = new UnityContainer();
```

Obviously, given the above code, it would be impossible to access the container *before* it has been set - Unity is doing exactly the same thing.

The fix is to inject it as a constructor argument:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Container { get; set; }
    public Form1(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Container = container;
        var invoice = Container.Resolve<Invoice>();
    }
}
```

### EDIT

Given your clarification I think what you should actually be doing is making your property an `Invoice` as so:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    [Dependency]
    public Invoice { get; set; }

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Note that you will still not be able to access the `Invoice` from inside the constructor for the same reason outlined earlier.

Comment: With constructor argument work fine, but what I want is use `DependencyAttribute` for let code more clean.

Comment: Properties are set *after* the constructor has run, so you can *never* access a property inside the constructor (unless you have set it yourself in the constructor). What you are asking for is simply not possible. However, I have thought of an alternative, which is probably a better way of doing it anyway - see edit...

Comment: Thank you by explanation I understand now.